# using class names to create array for a for each statement

Tags: jquery, arrays, join, each

I have a set of checkboxes with `span` elements as their titles. I want the text in the `span` to wrap with a url once the checkbox is checked. However, I do have the code down for selecting the `span` class names. In order for my code to work I have my checkbox id the same name as my `span`. This does work if I set the `array` myself but for some reason I cannot get my array to work when it is created with the script. Here's the code

HTML:

```
<div id="product_list" style="float:left; clear:right;">
<input type="checkbox" id="p01" name="system[]" value="p01" form="compare">
<span style="margin-left:20px;" class="p01">product one</span>
<br/>

<input type="checkbox" id="p02" name="system[]" value="p02" form="compare">
<span style="margin-left:20px;" class="p02">product two</span>
<br/>

<input type="checkbox" id="p04" name="system[]" value="p04" form="compare">
<span style="margin-left:20px;" class="p04">product three</span>
<br/>

<input type="checkbox" id="p05" name="system[]" value="p05" form="compare">
<span style="margin-left:20px;" class="p02">product four</span>
<br/>

</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
var arr = [];
arr = $('#product_list span').not('.hidden').map(function(i,e) {
return $(e).attr('class');
}).get().join(', ');

alert(arr);

    //arr = ["p01", "p02", "p03", "p04"]; works but not the above.

jQuery.each(arr , function(index, value){

$("#"+ value).click(function(){
// alert("clicked");
if ($(this).attr("checked") == "checked"){
$('.'+value).wrap('<a href="#" id="comparelink" target="_blank"></a>'); $('a').link('href', '#');    
}

else {
$('.'+value).unwrap('a');

}

});

});
```

​
[example](http://jsfiddle.net/STGef/57/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, your code is setting `arr` to a string as follows

```
"p01, p02, p04, p05"
```

Simply, remove the `String#join` to generate the array you want.

```
var arr = $('#product_list span').not('.hidden').map(function(i, e) {
    return $(e).attr('class');
}).get();
```

Furthermore, jQuery has no method `.link()`. I suppose you meant to use `.attr()`.

Use

```
$('a').attr('href', '#');
```

instead of

```
$('a').link('href', '#');
```

---

I applied some modifications to your code.

1. Usage of `change` event handler.
2. Cache of selector, such as `$span` and `$input`.
3. Usage of [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `.attr()`.
4. Usage of [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to get the `input` elements since all of them happen to be just before your `span` elements.
5. Change from `id` attribute to `class` attribute since `ID` are meant to be unique over all the DOM.

```
$('#product_list span').not('.hidden').each(function() {
    var $span = $(this), $input = $span.prev();
    $input.change(function() {
        if ($input.prop("checked")) {
            $span.wrap($('<a/>', {
                "href": "#",
                "class": "comparelink",
                "target": "_blank"
            }));
        } else {
            $span.unwrap('a');
        }
    });
});​
```

[**See it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9p6U/)

Comment: thank you Alexander and @charlietfl. Worked awesome. Also thank you pointing out the `link` too

Comment: `$('a').attr('href', '#');` will change every `<a>` in page... no idea what is wanted

Comment: @charlietfl, neither me. I suppose was meant to be completed afterwards

Comment: @Far, if you are open to suggestions, feel free to see my updated answer

Comment: thank you, it was included just to show what the intention of making the array was for. I really wasn't looking for a fix on the link thinking I didn't need to but you proved me wrong :-) Thank you again very much for helping me out on that. I'll read up more on the documentation of the `prop` and `prev`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `join()`.

```
arr = $('#product_list span').not('.hidden').map(function(i,e) {
return $(e).attr('class');
}).get();
```

`get()` unwraps the array from jQuery object

You could do this without using array, rather using simple traverse.

```
var $checkboxes = $('#product_list span').not('.hidden').prev();
    $checkboxes.click(function(){
         if( this.checked){
              /* "A" tag has problems...can't duplicate ID's using class and no idea what href you want*/              
              $(this).next('span').wrap('<a href="#" class="comparelink" target="_blank"></a>'); 
         }else{
              $(this).next().find('span').unwrap()
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not really building an array but a string (`"p01, p02, p03, p04"`).

Replace

```
var arr = [];
arr = $('#product_list span').not('.hidden').map(function(i,e) {
return $(e).attr('class');
}).get().join(', ');
```

with

```
var arr = $('#product_list span').not('.hidden').map(function(i,e) {
    return $(e).attr('class');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I almost figured that, lol but when I run this script it gives me `[object Object]`

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an alternative answer because it doesn't really address the array issue, but why do you need to use an array? Would this work for your code, it grabs all the input elements with a name of system[] and assigns the click event:

```
$('input[name="system[]"]').on('click', function() {
    var spanClass = $(this).attr('id');
    if ($(this).attr("checked") == "checked") {
        $('.' + spanClass).wrap('<a href="#" id="comparelink" target="_blank"></a>');
    }
    else {
        $('.' + spanClass).unwrap('a');
    }
});
```

​
You could also give those inputs a shared class like 'chkLink' and use that in place. Just seems like you're doing something really difficult for something that could be simplified... either that or I don't grasp the full intent of your application.